# Evaluating $y(1)$ in the initial value problem $\dot y = ty + \sin y , y(0)=10^{-2}$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, inequality, initial-value-problems

For the following initial value problem:
$$
\left\{ 
\begin{array}{}
\dot y=ty+\sin y \\ 
y(0)=10^{-2} 
\end{array}
\right. 
$$

I need to evaluate $y(1)$.

I thought about using the fact that $\dot y \leq ty+1$, and solve $\dot z=tz+1$, but I couldn't solve that. I was also given a hint to use the Integral form of the equation, that is $y=10^{-2}+\int_0^t(sy+\sin y)ds$, but I can't think of a way to use that.

Comment: Use the Picard iteration

Comment: see here http://mathfaculty.fullerton.edu/mathews/n2003/PicardIterationMod.html

Comment: It's a nice idea, but I can only perform one iteration. Isn't there another method which gives a more precise evaluation?

Answer (score 2):

For $y$ that small you get $\sin y\approx y$ so that you can obtain an approximate solution from
$$
\frac{y'}y=t+1\implies y(t)=y(0)\exp(\tfrac12t^2+t)
$$
thus $y(1)\approx 10^{-2}e^{1.5}=0.04481689$. As the error in the equation is in the scale of $10^{-6}$, the error in the solution is of the same scale, as the integration interval has length $1$. So at least the digits $0.0448$ should be correct, the next digit is $1$ or $2$ as the 6. digit is "dirty". The numerical solution $0.0448127724253...$ is exact to at least the first 10 decimal digits, which confirms the estimate.